# What is the difference between const and const {} in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, destructuring

When I study [Electron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_(software_framework)), I found two ways of getting a BrowserWindow object.

```
const {BrowserWindow} = require('electron')
```

and

```
const electron = require('electron')
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow
```

What is the difference between `const` and `const {}` in JavaScript?

I can't understand why the `const {}` can work. Do I miss anything important about JavaScript?

Answer (score 244, accepted):

The two pieces of code are equivalent but the first one is using the [ES6 destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to be shorter.

Here is a quick example of how it works:

```js
const obj = {
  name: "Fred",
  age: 42,
  id: 1
}

//simple destructuring
const { name } = obj;
console.log("name", name);

//assigning multiple variables at one time
const { age, id } = obj;
console.log("age", age);
console.log("id", id);

//using different names for the properties
const { name: personName } = obj;
console.log("personName", personName);
```

Comment: Your answer is helpful. I found the Mozilla developer website very hard to understand. Thanks.

Comment: `const { name, sex = "female" } = obj;`
if you want to create another variable at the same time

Answer (score 42):

Use:

```
const {BrowserWindow} = require('electron')
```

The above syntax uses [ES6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#6th_Edition_%E2%80%93_ECMAScript_2015). If you have an object defined as:

```
const obj = {
    email: "hello@gmail.com",
    title: "Hello world"
}
```

Now if we want to assign or use the email and title field of `obj`, then we don't have to write the whole syntax like

```
const email = obj.email;
const title = obj.title;
```

**This is old school now.**

We can use **ES6 destructuring** assignment, i.e., if our object contains 20 fields in the `obj` object, then we just have to write names of those fields which we want to use like this:

```
const { email,title } = obj;
```

**This is ES6 syntax-the simpler one**

It will automatically assign the email and title from `obj`; just the name has to be correctly stated for the required field.

Answer (score 29):

This is one of the new features in [ES6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#6th_Edition_%E2%80%93_ECMAScript_2015). The curly braces notation is a part of the so-called *destructuring assignment*. What this means is that, you no longer have to get the object itself and assign variables for each property you want on separate lines.  You can do something like:

```js
const obj = {
  prop1: 1,
  prop2: 2
}

// Previously you would need to do something like this:
const firstProp = obj.prop1;
const secondProp = obj.prop2;
console.log(firstProp, secondProp);
// etc.

// However, now you can do this on the same line:
const {prop1, prop2} = obj;
console.log(prop1, prop2);
```

As you have seen in the end, the functionality is the same—simply getting a property from an object.

There is also more to destructuring assignment. You can check the entire syntax in MDN: *[Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)*

Answer (score 5):

Other answers are good enough. I would suggest some useful features of [*Destructuring assignment*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

**Firstly, let's look at the following definition:**

> The destructuring assignment syntax is a JavaScript expression that
> makes it possible to `unpack values from arrays, or properties from objects, into distinct variables`.

**Features:**

1. *Destructure an array, index of each item in array act as property (Due to an *Array is an object in JavaScript*)*

   ```
   > const {0: first, 1: second} = [10, 20]
   console.log(first);   // 10
   console.log(second);  // 20
   ```
2. *Combine with [`Spread ...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) operator*

   ```
   > {a, b, ...rest} = {a: 10, b: 20, c: 30, d: 40}
   console.log(a); // 10
   console.log(b); // 20
   console.log(rest ); // {c: 30, d: 40}
   ```
3. *Default values*

   ```
   const {a = 10, b = 20} = {a: 1};

   console.log(a); // 1
   console.log(b); // 20
   ```
4. *Assigning to new variable names*

   ```
   const {p: a, q: b} = {p: 10, q: 20};

   console.log(a); // 10
   console.log(b); // 20
   ```