# What is the meaning of { variable } in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am going through an online article and I came across

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const { Schema } = mongoose;
```

May I know what is the meaning of `const { Schema } = mongoose;`.

Are we doing object initiation of `mongoose` to `Schema` variable or ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring

Comment: It's called *decomposition*. That `const` declaration means to create a variable called `Schema` whose value is that of the property with the same name in the object on the right-hand side of `=`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what is the difference between const and const {} in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41058569/what-is-the-difference-between-const-and-const-in-javascript)

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/q/54605286/691711

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In JavaScript, the `const { Schema } = mongoose;` syntax is something called object destructuring.

You can read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

But this statement is exactly equivalent to this:

```js
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
```