# How to combine all unique element in any given array property from array of object into single array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have below javascript array of object problem in which i have tag array property inside array of object. Tag array contain some value in each array of object. I wanted to get unique tag value from each array of object and combine into single array which will contain only unique tag.

```js
const obj = [{
  name: "ABC",
  tag: ["abc", "xyz"]
}, {
  name: "USA",
  tag: ["abc", "suv"]
}, {
  name: "ABC",
  tag: ["pot", "xyz"]
}]
```

I need the unique tag item into single array as per below.

```
const unique = ["abc", "xyz", "suv", "pot"];
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get all unique values in a JavaScript array (remove duplicates)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/get-all-unique-values-in-a-javascript-array-remove-duplicates)

Comment: @James I added an answer. Did you get a chance to look into that. Hope it will work as per your expectation.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) and [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

```js
const obj = [
  { name: 'ABC', tag: ['abc', 'xyz'] },
  { name: 'USA', tag: ['abc', 'suv'] },
  { name: 'ABC', tag: ['pot', 'xyz'] },
]

const res = [...new Set(obj.flatMap(({tag}) => tag))];

console.log(res)
```

Comment: Hi hgb123, As @mplungjan said, you should use `Destructure` to make your code more concise. You can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67265714/9071943). I've just updated your answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

A set will give you unique values:

- [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)
- [Array.prototype.flatMap()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)
- [Spread syntax (...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)
- [Unpacking properties from objects passed as a function parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#unpacking_properties_from_objects_passed_as_a_function_parameter)

```js
const obj = [{
  name: "ABC",
  tag: ["abc", "xyz"]
}, {
  name: "USA",
  tag: ["abc", "suv"]
}, {
  name: "ABC",
  tag: ["pot", "xyz"]
}]

const unique = [...new Set(obj.flatMap(({tag}) => tag))];

console.log(unique)
```

Comment: What makes your answer different from [@hgb123 's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71261909/9071943)?

Comment: @NguyễnVănPhong three identical answers were posted here within 30 seconds. It's just a coincidence.

Comment: @NguyễnVănPhong Now that you've edited that user's answer, nothing in the code is different — my answer just includes more information in the form of links to documentation about the APIs and patterns used.

Comment: Yeah, I see. @jsejcksn

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to filtered out the unique elements from an array.

**Demo :**

```js
const obj = [{
  name: "ABC",
  tag: ["abc", "xyz"]
}, {
  name: "USA",
  tag: ["abc", "suv"]
}, {
  name: "ABC",
  tag: ["pot", "xyz"]
}];

let arr = [];

obj.forEach((item) => {
    arr.push(...item.tag)
})

console.log([...new Set(arr)]);
```